# How to solve the error related with grid placement in pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I have been trying to generate a graph, but encountered the following error for the code mentioned below. Where I am going wrong? Please kindly help.

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/graphs/grid placement'
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
%\usegdlibrary{trees}

%\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 

%[level distance=10mm,
%every node/.style={fill=red!60,circle,inner sep=1pt},
%level 1/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=red!45}},
%level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=red!30}},
%level 3/.style={sibling distance=5mm,nodes={fill=red!25}}]
%\node {31}
%child {node {30}
%child {node {20}
%child {node {5}}
%child {node {4}}
%}
%child {node {10}
%child {node {9}}
%child {node {1}}
%}
%}
%child {node {20}
%child {node {19}
%child {node {1}}
%child[missing]
%}
%child {node {18}}
%};


%[level distance=10mm,sibling distance=5mm]
%\node {root} [grow=down]
%child
%{ node {1} }
%child
%{ node {2} }
%child
%{ node {3} }
%child[missing] { node {4} }
%child
%{ node {5} }
%child
%{ node {6} };


%[edge from parent/.style={draw,red,thick}]
%\node {root}
%child {node {left} edge from parent[dashed]}
%child {node {right}
%child {node {child}}
%child {node {child} edge from parent[draw=none]}
%};


%\graph [binary tree layout, level %distance=5mm] {
%4 -- {
%3 -- 0 -- 1[second],
%10 -- {
%8 -- {
%6 -- {5,7},
%9
%} } }
%};

\begin{graph}[noplacement, n=6,nodes={draw}] {
      a, b, c, d, e, f,
     };
\end{graph}     


%\graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, %radius=.75cm, empty nodes, n=8] {
%subgraph C_n [name=inner] <->[shorten %<=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
%subgraph C_n [name=outer]
%};

%\graph [grow right=2cm] { unsigned integer %-> d -> digit -> E };

%\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh %nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling %distance=0.5in]
%    {
%        4 -> { 
%          3 -> { 1 -> { 5}, 2,2 },
%          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 },
%          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 }
%        } 
%    };

[every path/.style={>=latex},every node/.style={draw,circle}]
  \node            (a) at (0,0)  { A };
  \node            (b) at (2,0)  { B };
  \node            (c) at (2,-2) { C };
  \node[rectangle] (d) at (0,-2) { D };
  \draw[->] (a) edge (b);
  \draw[->] (a) edge (c);
  \draw[->] (b) edge (c);
  \draw[<-] (c) edge (d);

 \begin{graph}[noplacement,nodes={draw,circle},edges={>=latex}] {
    A [at={(0,0)}] -> {
      B [at={(2,0)}] -> C [at={(2,-2)}],
      C -> D [at={(0,-2)},rectangle]
    }
  };
\end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are no [grid placement] or [noplacement] keys, so I have no idea what they are supposed to accomplish.  However, you should use \begin{scope}[every path/.style={>=latex},every node/.style={draw,circle}] ... \end{scope} in place of the floating option that is there now.

Comment: Your code does not produce the error you report because it never uses `grid placement`. The error concerns only `noplacement`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Agree about the scope, but there ***is*** a `grid placement` key and, while there isn't a `noplacement` key, there is a `no placement` one. Moreover, the code posted in the question loads the TikZ library which defines these keys. Or check the manual's index.

Answer (score 1):

`no placement` works as advertised provided you do not omit the space between the words.

`no placement` is intended for cases where you will specify the location of the nodes by hand, which does not seem to be the case for the first graph.

There is a key `grid placement`. However, if you are not using a `subgraph`, you must specify `wrap after` explicitly as it cannot be calculated automatically. I take it this is what you want for the first graph.

For example, also shifting the second and third sets to the right in order to see the effects of each group:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{graph}[grid placement, n=6, nodes={draw}, wrap after=3] {
      a, b, c, d, e, f,
    };
  \end{graph}
  \begin{scope}[every path/.style={>=latex}, every node/.style={draw, circle}, xshift=30mm]
    \node            (a) at (0,0)  { A };
    \node            (b) at (2,0)  { B };
    \node            (c) at (2,-2) { C };
    \node[rectangle] (d) at (0,-2) { D };
    \draw[->] (a) edge (b);
    \draw[->] (a) edge (c);
    \draw[->] (b) edge (c);
    \draw[<-] (c) edge (d);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=60mm]
    \begin{graph}[no placement, nodes={draw, circle}, edges={>=latex}, ] {
        A [at={(0,0)}] -> {
          B [at={(2,0)}] -> C [at={(2,-2)}],
          C -> D [at={(0,-2)},rectangle]
        }
      };
    \end{graph}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: placing on a grid, standard, no automatic placement]